# Machine freezes once it hits swap space under heavy load

Tags: swap, freeze, troubleshooting

I encountered several crashes of my machine. Meanwhile, I can reproduce it when I start a program that fills up all memory. Once the system starts writing to the swap file, the system freezes and I have to reboot.

In the journal, I see no useful log information before the crash, for instance:

```
Mar 23 19:12:01 classen systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Mar 23 19:12:01 classen systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Mar 23 19:12:08 classen wpa_supplicant[757]: wlp3s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with ...
-- Reboot --
Mar 23 19:17:03 classen systemd-journald[380]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/) is 8.0M, max 796.6M, 788.6M free.
```

Actually, I don't know to troubleshoot the problem. I hope that someone has seen something similar, and can point me in the right direction. The strange thing is that after working for a while, my system is able to swap to some degree (at least, `top` showed that some of the swap space was occupied). The freezes happen only under heavy load to the swap file.

---

Here is my setup:

`$ lsblk`

```
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                    8:2    0   238G  0 part  
  └─MyStorage           254:0    0   238G  0 crypt 
    ├─MyStorage-swapvol 254:1    0    16G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─MyStorage-rootvol 254:2    0   222G  0 lvm   /
sdb                       8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 931.5G  0 part  
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Relevant part of `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/MyStorage-rootvol   /    btrfs   rw,noatime,ssd,autodefrag,compress=lzo,space_cache      0 0
/dev/mapper/MyStorage-swapvol none   swap    defaults        0 0

UUID=63A7-3F81          /boot        vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2
```

`$ swapon --summary`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-1                               partition   16777212    0   -1
```

I am running Arch Linux with a 4.4.5 kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux classen 4.4.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 10 07:38:19 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

hooks in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block encrypt lvm2 resume filesystems keyboard fsck"
```

Comment: You're probably just thrashing. Run `pidstat -U $USER -r 1` while running the memory-gobbling program. When VSZ gets to be about as big as memory, that's when you watch `majflt/s`. If it goes high, stays high and pidstat keeps working, then it's thrashing because of that process.

Comment: You might want to consider using the zram kernel module instead of  (or as well as) a swap partition.  it's a compressed RAM-based block device meant for use as a swap device.  built-in compression means a 4GB zram can swap 6 or 8GB or more, depending on how compressible the swap data is....and much faster than swapping to hard disk or even SSD.   https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/zram.txt BTW, if you're actually using anywhere near 16GB of swap then you **really** need to add more RAM.  swap is useful but is not something that should be used as a substitute for RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! You could be right that it is just thrashing. I'll keep that in mind when I can test again.

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out, that the swap partition was broken. Since 17.04 it is anyway standard to use a swapfile instead, so after changing to this I got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some experiment, I can confirm that it was actually thrashing in combination with a huge swap partition (16 GB).

Thanks for the comments, Otheus and cas, you had the right intuition. I underestimated the effect. Maybe because previous machines that I used had smaller swap spaces (in comparison to the memory), so eventually the memory hungry process was killed.

As some safety measures, I will reduce the maximum swap space on my system. I also defined a per-process limit to guard against a single process blowing up the memory:

```
# limit memory usage to 10G per process
ulimit -Sv 10000000
```

Tools like `vmstat 1` can help to analyze the problem.